# Center block or inline-block (single instance per row) elements without wrapper but with padding-like gap

Tags: html, css

The cleanest way to center (inline)block element without wrapper is:

```css
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%)
```

Vertical centering is similar.

Now I need to add gaps between:

- viewport left edge and element's left edge
- viewport right edge and element's right edge

when viewport becomes narrower and approaches to element's maximal width. Both gaps marked by red arrows in below image.

Possible to reach it without wrapper?

I prepared the sandbox to save your time.

[image]

```css
.MessageBox {

  /* it matters */
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;

  /* just decorations */
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MessageBox"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with margin but the trick is to consider it inside the left property too.

```css
.MessageBox {

  /* it matters */
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
  max-width: 600px;
  margin:0 20px;

  /* just decorations */
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MessageBox"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
```

With CSS variables you can easily adjust it:

```css
.MessageBox {
  --gap:20px;
  /* it matters */
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - var(--gap));
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
  max-width: 600px;
  margin:0 var(--gap);

  /* just decorations */
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MessageBox"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
```

You can also do it considering only width:

```css
.MessageBox {
  --gap:20px;
  /* it matters */
  position: relative;
  margin:auto;
  
  max-width: 600px;
  width:calc(100% - 2*var(--gap));

  /* just decorations */
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="MessageBox"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You are really genius.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to center ***(inline)block*** element without wrapper is to make `body{text-align:center}` .

- I can't see any inline(block) element in your code
- If it's block then `margin:auto` will work
- Even though if there is no wrapper, you still have html and body as parent
- Center align is the easiest way to center any inline element

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.MessageBox {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="MessageBox"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to admit that failed to state what I need. "I can't see any inline(block) element in your code" - the is a plain block in my code, but I want this question will be actual for inline-block (single per row) elements too. "Even though if there is no wrapper, you still have html and body as parent" - afraid no. What if blue box from my example is being conditionally rendered and other elements which could be rendered instead of blue box don't need paddings which you defined.